# Why is there always a way for a packet to find the default route?

Tags: ip, routing, iproute

I have an interesting problem that I would like to understand more.

This is my following rules list:

```
# ip rule show
0:  from all lookup local
32761:  from all to 188.40.122.95 lookup vpn
32762:  from all to 178.63.26.145 lookup vpn
32763:  from all to 176.9.71.146 lookup vpn
32764:  from all to 159.69.66.229 lookup vpn
32765:  from 192.168.100.0/28 lookup vpn
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

and this is how it looks like the VPN table

```
# ip route show table vpn
default dev tun0 scope link
192.168.100.0/28 dev eth0 scope link
```

If I send a ping to the IP addr `88.40.122.95` the outbound interface is `tun0` and this is understandable because in the `table vpn` we find the default route.

However if I remove the default route the package still find its way and it can go out via the interface `eth0`.

Why so?  I would expect that specifying those rules

```
32761:  from all to 188.40.122.95 lookup vpn
32762:  from all to 178.63.26.145 lookup vpn
32763:  from all to 176.9.71.146 lookup vpn
32764:  from all to 159.69.66.229 lookup vpn
```

the packet must respects the rule in the `vpn` table and if the table does not have any default then it should fail.

The reason of this design is because I would like that the traffic generated for those IPs goes out only and only via the `tun0` and if for some reasons the `default` rule is not found then it must fail.

Comment: What are you trying to do. Edit the question to make clear. Am I correct in thinking you are trying to prevent routes that avoid the VPN?

Comment: exactly I'm trying to have routes that avoid the VPN.

Comment: What are you trying to do. **Edit the question to make clear.**

Comment: I've edited. it should be clearer

Comment: Aren't you trying to solve a firewall issue with a routing solution?

Comment: @Ginnungagap No I'm not trying to solve a firewall issue with a routing solution. This is a pure routing discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the following rule to the route table

```
ip route add unreachable default metric 100 table vpn
```

and this is how it looks like:

```
➜ ip route show table vpn
default dev tun0 scope link
unreachable default metric 100
192.168.100.0/28 dev eth0 scope link
```

So when the default route table is present then the traffic can go out but when the default route table is not present then the rule with metric `100` will be matched and so the Internet will be unreachable.

Tested and it works. Thanks to A.B. to point out to man page and also to Eduardo

Answer (score 1):

> However if I remove the default route the package still find its way and it can go out via the interface eth0.

Yes, because there is no longer a match in the vpn table, and ip route goes onto the next lookups.

To avoid that you can use the `throw` route type at the end of your vpn table, something like:

```
ip route add throw default table vpn
```

Then, in the absence of a default route inside the vpn table, the lookup will stop there.

Check the man page for `ip-route`. There are other types of routes you might find interesting in your case: `prohibit`, `unreachable` and `blackhole`.

Comment: Thanks this is was what I was looking but I've tried and it does not work. I get

`➜  ~ ip route show table vpn
default dev tun0 scope link
192.168.100.0/28 dev eth0 scope link
➜  ~ ip route add throw default table vpn

RTNETLINK answers: File exists`

This happens because the default entry is already in place so i cannot add another entry

Comment: man page: "throw [...] **Without policy routing** it is equivalent to the absence of the route in the routing table." *throw* gets the ENETUNREACH only when applied on the last looked up table (usually the main table).

Comment: yeah that's true. reading better the man page throw would not work. the problem is that any kind of rule that is added as `default` won't be added because a `default` rule already exists

Comment: I understood here. I would add two default rules one having different metrics

Comment: ok I think I've solved.